# I need a make code that make a check that is ExtJS Checkbox checked or not

Tags: extjs

I need a make code that make a check that is Ext JS Checkbox checked or not.

I use a code like this:

```
var RadioPeriod = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
             id:'period',
             //xtype: 'radio',
               checked: true,
               fieldLabel: '',
               labelSeparator: '',
               boxLabel: 'Period',
               name: 'employment_type',
               inputValue: 'period'
               // listener below
          });
```

I just need a short listener.

Btw, I need a service that cost some monthly fee for me and there has fulltime employees to answerd my questions very fast because I really need answers for my questions impliedly. And I want similar service than you make for free.

I don't want to continue support of Sencha, Inc, because its not fit to my needs and I have no Venture Capital Investor to pay for Sencha, Inc. from Partner Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
id:'period',
xtype: 'radio',
fieldLabel: '',
labelSeparator: '',
boxLabel: 'Period',
name: 'employment_type',
inputValue: 'period'
   listeners : {
      change : function(field, newValue, oldValue, options) {
      if(newValue)
      {
         //code executed when checkbox is checked
      }
      else
      {
         //code executed when checkbox is not checked
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RadioPeriod.getValue()`

It's all in API docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-method-getValue

Comment: Hi, can this done with listener? But if I try to use it whole my GUI disappears.

Comment: Yes it can. Please update your question with the code you use, otherwise we can't really help you.